# Encoding and iterating json with python but multiple root elements

Tags: python, json, parsing, encoding

Good evening everyone, 
I have python script which writes some data of a list to a json file. The script iterates through the list and write the json file, it works but I have a problem: the root element gets iterated too and it gets written thousand of times in json file so it becomes invalid.
This is part how json should look like:

```
{
   "acList": [{
      "Icao": "400025",
      "Alt": 24475,
      "GAlt": 24475,
      "AltT": 0,
      "Call": "TEST1234",
      "Tisb": false,
      "TrkH": false,
      "Sqk": "0644",
      "Help": false,
      "VsiT": 0,
      "Gnd": false,
      "SpdTyp": 0,
      "CallSus": false,
      "Trt": 1
  },
  {
     "Icao": "49528A",
     "Alt": 17375,
     "GAlt": 17632,
     "InHg": 30.177166,
     "AltT": 0,
     "Call": "TAP362",
     "Lat": 50.813118,
     "Long": -1.117325,
     "Mlat": false,
     "Tisb": false,
     "Spd": 357.0,
     "Trak": 39.9,
     "TrkH": false,
     "Sqk": "7473",
     "Help": false,
     "Vsi": -1472,
     "VsiT": 0,
     "Gnd": false,
     "SpdTyp": 0,
     "CallSus": false,
     "Trt": 2
  }]
}
```

While this is what I get:

```
{
    "acList": [
      {
     "GAlt": 33975,
     "Mlat": false,
     "Tisb": false,
     "Trt": 1,
     "Help": false,
     "InHg": 0,
     "CallSus": false,
     "Long": 17.1752,
     "TrkH": false,
     "Icao": "02A196",
     "Sqk": "3710",
     "Call": "TU217",
     "Trak": 261,
     "Gnd": false,
     "Lat": 37.8024,
     "Vsi": 0,
     "Alt": 33975,
     "AltT": 0,
     "Spd": 428,
     "SpdTyp": 0,
     "VsiT": 0
   }
 ]
  }{
     "acList": [
      {
     "GAlt": 0,
     "Mlat": false,
     "Tisb": false,
     "Trt": 1,
     "Help": false,
     "InHg": 0,
     "CallSus": false,
     "Long": 14.4933,
     "TrkH": false,
     "Icao": "4D2027",
     "Sqk": "2704",
     "Call": "KM103",
     "Trak": 113,
     "Gnd": false,
     "Lat": 35.8478,
     "Vsi": 0,
     "Alt": 0,
     "AltT": 0,
     "Spd": 0,
     "SpdTyp": 0,
     "VsiT": 0
   }
 ]
 }{
```

As you can see I got the root element repeated and repeated. What I should achieve is keeping only the first one root element and the right punctuation of course. This is my actual code in Python:

```
count = 0
for hex in keys:
    data = {
        "acList": [{
        "Icao": icao[count],
        "Alt": alt[count],
        "GAlt": alt[count],
        "InHg": 0,
        "AltT": 0,
        "Call": call[count],
        "Lat": lat[count],
        "Long": long[count],
        "Mlat": False,
        "Tisb": False,
        "Spd": speed[count],
        "Trak": track[count],
        "TrkH": False,
        "Sqk": sqk[count],
        "Help": False,
        "Vsi": vsi[count],
        "VsiT": 0,
        "Gnd": False,
        "SpdTyp": 0,
        "CallSus": False,
        "Trt": count + 1
        }]
     }
   count = count + 1
   jsonData = json.dumps(data, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
   print(jsonData)
   with open('aircraft.json', 'a') as f:
      f.write(jsonData)
```

Sorry for the extremely long post, I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you doing individual appends to a file? It will be difficult to produce a valid json this way. Rather, build the data-structure up in memory, *then serialize the whole thing into json*.

Comment: The for-loop should create a single list of dicts. This list should then be added to the root dict: `data = {'acList': lst}`. Finally, the root dict should be dumped to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, your loop logical is wrong. To output JSON string as you expected, your target `data` should be a structure like `data=dict(acList=[object ...])`. For your case, you even do not need the loop, the list comprehension is enough:

```
data = dict(acList=[
    {
    "Icao": icao[count],
    "Alt": alt[count],
    "GAlt": alt[count],
    "InHg": 0,
    "AltT": 0,
    "Call": call[count],
    "Lat": lat[count],
    "Long": long[count],
    "Mlat": False,
    "Tisb": False,
    "Spd": speed[count],
    "Trak": track[count],
    "TrkH": False,
    ....
    } for count in len(keys)]
)
```

Thanks.